# Unable to do grails run-app on 2.4.4 with mongo 3.0.2

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I've upgraded grails to 2.4.4 and using mongodb 3.0.2.

When I'm firing the app with run-app command it fails with following exception:

```
| Error 2014-11-06 15:13:18,026 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;
Message: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getDependencyComparator()Ljava/util/Comparator;
    Line | Method
->>  131 | invokeMethod              in grails.spring.DynamicElementReader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    754 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
```

I tried debugging the problem and found that, I'd added latest gorm-release in my BuildConfig.groovy as

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.3.RELEASE'
compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.3.RELEASE'
test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.3.RELEASE'
```

When I'm removing these dependencies from my BuildConfig.groovy file, app runs properly. But I need these latest dependencies. Any idea please?

Comment: Are there more LPG messages before the one you shared with us?

Comment: Thanks @JeffBeck. No there were only those messages I shared. But I get it resolved. https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11813

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. The issue was with the **grails-datastore-gorm** dependency, which was pulling in an older version of **spring-beans**.

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11813

Answer (score 0):

Grails 2.4.4 using spring 4.x bean version.

This problem arise when some of your external dependency uses spring 3.X
To find which dependency adding spring 3.X jar run below command

**grails dependency-report**

Then Find the spring-beans-3.X jar 
and exclude this dependency in **Build.groovy** as below

compile com.sample.componenet.server.utilities:sample-logger:1.0.0 
           excludes org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.8.RELEASE